# How to position a vertex by inputting numbers and make other vertices move relative to it

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have a simple cube with 8 vertices. I would like to move one of the vertices (let's call it the "designated vertex") to a specific position on one of the global axes (by entering a number) and have the other 7 move relative to it without distorting the shape of the cube.

I would prefer it if I could choose which vertices should move relative to the "designated vertex" instead of the whole object (I don't know how to do either).

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean 8 vertices? Or not a cube but a plane? Cube can be made only of 8 vertices or it's not a cube. Either way you can use pivot point set to Active Element. Then after selecting all vertices select designated one last and move to e.g. 3D cursor position

Comment: Oops. Yes, 8 vertices. I'll correct it. It doesn't change anything, though ;)
What you suggested would translate the vertices on all 3 axes, right? I would like to move them on one specific global axis. Is that possible? I guess a workaround would be to first snap the 3D cursor to the designated vertex, then input a number in one of the 3D cursor's axes and finally snap selection to 3D cursor, but I'm hoping there's a more convenient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more comfortable to use Object mode with its snapping tools in order to move object only on one global axis. However editing certain vertex is done in Edit mode.

A way to workaround (see below as to why) is to use **[Hook](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html)** modifier. It will allow you move object which vertex is hooked to in Object mode while all other vertices will follow it after you set up the modifier.

1. Enter Edit mode, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, in the opening menu choose *Hook to New Object* (it's more convenient to use created new empty for that).
   [image]
2. While still in Edit mode, choose vertices you want to be moved with the "designated" one and click *Assign* in the **Hook** modifier settings.
   [image]
3. Now the "designated" vertex will be in the same place as empty and follow it, and all other vertices will follow the empty.

However you still need to choose proper axis to move along (<kbd>G</kbd> > <kbd>X</kbd> > ... etc) or use snapping to cursor which is moving along all axes. Here's why this is a workaround  - you can move 3D cursor anywhere, switch *Pivot Point* to 3D Cursor, select hook-empty and scale it to 0 along desired axis.

Hooked object will turn into ugly flat rug, but it's easily fixable - just reset scale of the empty with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: I wish there were a more convenient way, but this is better than nothing. Thank you, R El Clein.